# Programmatically change listview so that it is checkable

Tags: android-listview

I've made a decent effort to find a similar question and failed, so please forgive me if this is redundant pollution.

I have a ListView and an ImageButton defined in the xml file "my_layout" corresponding to my Activity as follows:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/listViewItems"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  ></ListView>
```

and

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_delete_dark"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
    android:layout_weight="1">     
</ImageButton>
```

I then populate the ListView programmatically in the onCreate() method of my Activity as follows:

public class ViewItemsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemClickListener{

```
ImageButton buttonDelete;
ListView listViewItems;
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    buttonDeleteQuestion = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    listViewQuestions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    //get data from sql table containing items
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    String [] items = dbHandler.getItems();        //get data to populate ListView


    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {        
        case R.id.buttonDelete:         
        listViewItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listViewItems.setItemChecked(0, true);
        break;
        //other cases are irrelevant
        }   

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    //non relevant code
}
```

}

Everything works as it should except that I want the ListView to change, in appearance and functionality, as a result of clicking buttonDelete, so that it displays checkmarks to the right of each row which can be checked by clicking on them.

It was my understanding that setChoiceMode(ListView.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) and setItemChecked(i,true) would have this effect, but clearly I've missed something as it does not.

I am quite new to android and so it is possible that I've wasted someone's time with trivialities, for which I apologize.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really simple, and is the following:

in the onClick event corresponding to buttonDelete, I simply created a new adapter whose layout id is *simple_list_item_multiple_choice* and assigned it to the ListView with the lines

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

which did the trick.